# Cassandra JDBC INSERT does not work all the time

Tags: jdbc, cassandra

I have executed 1000 inserts to a cassandra cluster. But it seems only 5 rows are in the table. How is this possible? I know there is some sort of a cashing mechanism where cassandra doesn't post inserts. But how can I finalize the insert

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) { 
                try { 
            String testIns = 
        "INSERT INTO keyspace.testtable ( var1, var . . . ) " + 
        "  VALUES ( "  . . . ); " 
        ; 
        session.execute( testIns ) ; 
        System.out.println("Row " + i );
                } 
                catch (Exception e) { 

                }
            }
```

But this talbe `SELECT * FROM keyspace.testtable` contains only 6 rows. Why ?  How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One way that it is possible, is because of the cardinality of your PRIMARY KEY.

Cassandra PRIMARY KEYs are unique.  So if my table definition looks like this:

```
cassdba@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE singlePrimaryKey (
                                 key1 text PRIMARY KEY, letter1 text);
```

And then I INSERT six rows...

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO singleprimarykey (key1,letter1)
                                 VALUES ('A','A');
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO singleprimarykey (key1,letter1)
                                 VALUES ('A','B');
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO singleprimarykey (key1,letter1)
                                 VALUES ('A','C');
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO singleprimarykey (key1,letter1)
                                 VALUES ('A','D');
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO singleprimarykey (key1,letter1)
                                 VALUES ('A','E');
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO singleprimarykey (key1,letter1)
                                 VALUES ('A','F');
```

I see this when I SELECT from the entire table:

```
cassdba@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM singleprimarykey ;

 key1 | letter1
------+---------
    A |       F

(1 rows)
```

> How is this possible?

As you can see, this is how multiple INSERTs became one row.